# How to prevent android maps from scrolling outside boundaries

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I've been unable to find an example how to limit scrolling of android Google maps to defined coordinates or preferably not outside a ground overlay.

There are some examples of extending MapView and overriding the onScroll method, but the MapViewActivity which MapView needs, seems to be deprecated.

I am currently using GoogleMap class with SupportMapFragment, which seems not to support such a thing.

there is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270863/preventing-users-from-going-outside-map-boundaries) with an answer which is a bad hack and I rather not use it.

So is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible without bad hacks as of 3.1.36. You may want to post a feature request on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype=Android2) if nobody requested that already.