# How to create a navigation system for my college using google maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation

I am creating a project which helps students to navigate inside the campus.So i want to restrict my google maps view to my college and develop a navigation system to help the student reach his/her destination.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your own application which uses the google maps API.

For information about the API check this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: Yes I have created my application and even added the google maps into my application.But then restricting it to just my college view is where I am stuck.

Comment: I see, you should check this then: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977078/limit-scrolling-and-zooming-google-maps-android-api-v2