# Google Maps with TileProvider: different zoom level on zoom

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using `GoogleMaps` for Android API and a custom `TileProvider` which uses a URL to get a tile in the format zoom/x/y to show a custom world map.

Nothing fancy here. The app used to use Open Street Map. What I noticed, is that at a certain zoom level it shows higher detailed images.

It looks like the zoomlevel is different for OSM opposed to GoogleMaps. This results into a higher `zoom` value in the URL for OSM, while the GoogleMaps will put a lower number there which results in a more pixelated tile.

What is the difference here (or did the previous developer do something in OSM to make this happen)?

What I would like to do is, if Google Maps wants to request zoom level 5, I actually want to get zoom level 8. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps is not Open Street Maps. According to [Maximum Zoom Imagery Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maxzoom), the zoom levels available to Google Maps API is 0 to 18:

> "The Google Maps API provides map tiles at various zoom levels for map
>   type imagery. Most roadmap imagery is available from zoom levels 0 to
>   18, for example. Satellite imagery varies more widely as this imagery
>   is not generated, but directly photographed."

Since you're on Android, some code samples from this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977078/limit-scrolling-and-zooming-google-maps-android-api-v2) might help.