# How to crop Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to know is there any way to crop a Google V2 Map to only show a certain country and not the whole earth?

Programatically or in the xml.

The point is to limit the area of the map the user can view and pan around.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [limit scrolling and zooming Google Maps Android API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977078/limit-scrolling-and-zooming-google-maps-android-api-v2) specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40269234/295004)