# Google Maps V2 - Android - Get a list of Markers

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to get a list Markers(using GMaps V2 for Android) similar to the getOverlays() method I used in GMaps V1.1 for Android here:

```
private MapView mapView; 

mapView.getOverlays().add(overlay);
```

How can I do something similar to what I did above but with Markers?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

> How can I do something similar to what I did above but with Markers?

When you call `addMarker()`, save the resulting `Marker` object in a collection of your choice (e.g., `ArrayList<Marker>`).

Comment: What about getting the `MyLocation` marker if you called `setMyLocationEnabled(true)`?

Comment: @mattblang: That is not a `Marker`, and so you cannot retrieve it as one.

Comment: [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828217/android-map-v2-zoom-to-show-all-the-markers) has an easy method for zooming to the correct level to include everything, but I guess if I am wanting to include the `MyLocation` marker then the solution may be a bit more complicated.

Comment: @mattblang: Theoretically, if you use `LocationClient`, you should be getting the same location data as what the map uses, and so you just add that to the `LatLngBounds.Builder`.

Comment: I moved this to a [new SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109212/zoom-to-the-closest-level-that-still-shows-all-markers-including-the-blue-myloc).

Comment: What about cluster markers, which aren't created until the user taps a marker and an event is fired?

Comment: @NathanM: I have no idea, sorry.

Answer (score 7):

Alternative to the correct answer from CommonsWare would be using [Android Maps Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/), which adds `getMarkers()` function to `GoogleMap`.

Btw. `mapView.getOverlays().add(overlay)` code from Maps V1 is a very bad design choice. You should not give out `List` for modification. So this will not work with Extensions library.