# Zoom to the closest level that still shows all markers, including the blue MyLocation marker

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I would like to zoom and position my `GoogleMap` such that all markers, including the blue `MyLocation` marker, are visible.  [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828217/android-map-v2-zoom-to-show-all-the-markers) shows how to do this for all manually added markers, but I am not sure how to get a handle to the `MyLocation` marker, which is automatically added after calling `setMyLocationEnabled(true)`, in order to pass it to the `LatLngBounds.Builder`.

I have tried using `GoogleMap.getMyLocation()`, and I am calling it in `onPostCreate`, after the map has been fully initialized.  The call returns `null` though.  [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13830598/1747491) talks about a bug with `getMyLocation()`, but also mentions that it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

To add to that `LatLng` of my location blue dot, use `GoogleMap.getMyLocation()` or if you want to update camera every time that location changes, `GoogleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(...)` and then convert `Location` to `LatLng`.

Comment: I am calling `getMyLocation()` in `onPostCreate`, but I just get `null`.  [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13830598/1747491) talks about a bug with the function, but also says that it was supposedly fixed.

Comment: @mattblang `onPostCreate` is too early to call `getMyLocation`. Use listener or call it in when some button is clicked.

Comment: I tried it in `onResume` as well to see if it would work, but still `null`.  The problem with `onLocationChanged` is that the listener won't fire on initialization.  I noticed that `getMyLocation` is deprecated, so I switched to the methods they use in the demo file that is referenced in the `getMyLocation` documentation.  Using the SO question that I linked, I was able to get it working.  The one remaining problem is that the padding doesn't do anything, so markers are on the very edge.