# How to retrieve current Google map destination on Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-api-3

I am building an Android app that needs to run in the background and act when user uses Google map. Specifically, when use sets a a direction and navigation starts, I want to retrieve the target address and act on it.

The question: is it possible for third party app to retrieve the target address?

I was thinking that this can be done by retrieving the list of markers as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367594/google-maps-v2-android-get-a-list-of-markers).

Is this the right approach?

An secondary issue will be if there is way to have an intent that can wake up my app when the navigation starts.

Comment: Hi Klaus. Did you find any solution to this problem? I am also trying to do the same thing as explained by you.

Comment: No, there doesn't seem to be a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon quite simply the intents launched by Google Maps are not exposed to other applications (or in other words, when you create a nagivation task in Google Maps, there's no actual callback launched that can be hooked to by another app.)

However, assuming the navigation task will create a notification, you could perhaps abuse that notification and it's content to recognize navigation is currently running.

Though more importantly, what's the functionality you aim at with this? Likely you'd be better off implementing the Maps-API in your own app and handling everything from there.

Comment: Thanks for input. What about retrieving the current destination. Any hint?