# Getting the markers count on Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, markers

Is there are function in GoogleMaps Android API which can give me the count of Markers drawn on the Map (not only the on-screen visible markers)?

Comment: If you are drawing marker yourself, you did probably have them stored in some array or list. You can get the count from there

Comment: If you have been display marker on map it means you should have array of that all position so you can get total size of all array which is use for display marker

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16375757/5783098

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No function for this in the GoogleMaps API. 
Add [Map Extension](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-maps-extensions/) to your android project then you can simply call the function getMarkers() to get the count of markers on the map.