# Zoom to Fit All Markers on LeafletJS Map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

After adding a series of markers to a LeafletJS map, is it possible to get Leaflet to zoom and realign it's focus to show every marker? I see [many similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416041/zoom-to-fit-all-markers-on-map-google-maps-v2) to do with Google Maps but none for Leaflet.

Something like:

```
map.fitAllMarkers();
```

I've also noticed [several functions in Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-fitbounds) to get the bounds of the map, but I'm not sure how to employ those to the desired effect.

Answer (score 10):

You could also take advantage of the purposely made [`featureGroup.getBounds()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup-getbounds) method to have the map fitting the extent of your markers:

```js
var fg = L.featureGroup([arrayOfMarkers]).addTo(map);

map.fitBounds(fg.getBounds());
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/28/

Answer (score 3):

In the end, this is actually quite simple, though not united into one function. First, you need to create a Leaflet bounds object:

```
var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds();
```

Then, for each marker on the map:

```
bounds.extend(markerObject.getLatLng());
```

Finally, apply the new bounds to the map:

```
mapObject.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: This giving northeast and southeast objects, the same latlngs

Comment: I'm getting 'Uncaught Error: Bounds are not valid.' on https://hasan.d8u.us/cal.html?auth=test@test.com -- help?