# Attain maximum zoom on google map showing all markers

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming, google-maps-android-api-2

i have 5 markers to display on the map, out of which 4 are very near to each other and the fifth one is a little bit distant to these 4. now when i display the map i want all these 5 markers to be shown on map and the with the highest possible zoom. i dont care whether they are on the border of the screen or in the center of the screen.i mean the markers can be scattered on the screen but all i want is that all markers should visible to the user and with the highest possible zoom.

i have tried this [Android map v2 zoom to show all the markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828217/android-map-v2-zoom-to-show-all-the-markers) . but the result is that it is showing all markers at the center of the map with very little zoom. actually i have calculated screen dimensions using this code.

```
       DisplayMetrics metrics=new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    float height=metrics.heightPixels/metrics.xdpi;
    float width=metrics.widthPixels/metrics.ydpi;
```

but i dont know why there is very little zoom. But wen i saw android documentation,  i think the function is doing justice by doing whatever it  said it will do.

```
  public static CameraUpdate newLatLngBounds (LatLngBounds bounds, int width, int height, int padding)

  Returns a CameraUpdate that transforms the camera such that the specified 
 latitude/longitude bounds are centered on screen within a bounding box of specified 
 dimensions at the greatest possible zoom level. You can specify additional padding, 
  to further restrict the size of the bounding box. The returned CameraUpdate has a 
  bearing of 0 and a tilt of 0.

 Unlike newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int), you can use the CameraUpdate returned by
 this method to change the camera prior to the map's the layout phase, because the 
 arguments specify the desired size of the bounding box.
```

as it says it keeps all the markers at the center of the map. i do not want that. i want all the markers visible to the user with the maximum possible zoom and markers scattered. can anybody please help me?

Comment: then why do you need bounds in the first place.

Comment: you can set bounds between the left most marker(latlng) and the right most marker(latlng). LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
                      .include(leftmostlatlng)
                      .include(rightmostlatlng)
                      .build();

Comment: check this also https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition.Builder and this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views for zoom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of float width and height is incorrect.

What your width holds now is inches (value of approx. 2 on phones). You need not to divide pixels width.