# Android Google maps API V2 center markers

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Is there a way to make a map zoom in as far as possible but keeping all of the markers on screen at the same time. 
I have six markers in a non uniform shape. I was thinking of just taking their centre and locating the map to that, but I still then do not know how far programmatically I can zoom in the map.

These markers change location every time the map is created. Ideally I would have a script that zooms the map in so all are included in the view.

So you understand. I am creating the markers one at a time from json with the following line in a loop.

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat,lng)).title(c.getString("title")));
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should use the CameraUpdate class to do (probably) all programmatic map movements.

To do this, first calculate the bounds of all the markers like so:

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
for each (Marker m : markers) {
    builder.include(m.getPosition());
}

LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
```

Then obtain a movement description object by using the factory: CameraUpdateFactory:

```
int padding = 0; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
```

Finally move the map:

```
googleMap.moveCamera(cu);
```

Or if you want an animation:

```
googleMap.animateCamera(cu);
```

*Got from another post: [Android map v2 zoom to show all the markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828217/android-map-v2-zoom-to-show-all-the-markers/14828739#14828739)

Comment: Could you please link to the original post you obtained this from for some more context.

Comment: Thats the entire thing. any way here's it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14828739/1837759

Comment: Thank you. This line is causing me confusion though foreach (Marker m : markers) {
How do I obtain the markers?

Comment: u can do without it too just use ur marker object to do it. builder.include(m.getPosition()); Here m is the marker object.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at this:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views#changing_camera_position

Comment: This is the best just update to latest you never know when google is going to remove that entire package :p