# Get map center in maps version 2 of google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am upgrading my google maps version from 1 to version 2, but I have a problem as i used to use the ***getMapCenter()*** but i am not able to use it in v2

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904505/how-to-get-center-of-map-for-v2-android-maps

Comment: you can also refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17614029/1396082

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for posting the same question as it was already answered here [How to get center of map for v2 android maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904505/how-to-get-center-of-map-for-v2-android-maps) but i missed that

The solution here is
mMap.getCameraPosition().target

Thank you, All

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gMap.getCameraPosition().target`

where `gMap` is the GoogleMap instance from your activity. 
This will return a LatLng object which is the coordinate of the center of the map.

According to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition.html), the target is "The location that the camera is pointing at."