# How to initialize a google map so that marker placed is visible in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have recently deployed Google map API in my android application. The problem is that the marker placed on the map is not visible until user scroll/navigate over the view where map's fragment is deployed.

problem is" **How to focus the Google map to the marker of a specific location on initializing.**

***EDITED*: 25 AUGUST 2017**

I have placed the marker for a particular location using following this [blog post](http://androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2)

**PROBLEM**

I am trying to view my marker directly when a user sees the map. Not by scrolling the map to see the marker.

Comment: Can you tell us what have you tried so far?

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/ I have place marker using following this link

Comment: I have place the marker for particular location but i am trying to view my marker directly when user see the map. Not by scrolling the map to see the marker.

Comment: @MicheleLacorte i am working on the your link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to animate or move the map to the place where the marker is placed. I have pasted a snippet which should help you achieve that. Implement OnMapReadyCallback interfere and once the map is ready you should get a callback thru onMapReady(). This code only for your reference. You can place the marker related code wherever you need and works fine.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    LatLng location = new LatLng(<latitude>, <longitude>);
    CameraPosition target = CameraPosition.builder().target(location).zoom(15).build();
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(target), 5000, null);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location));
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613940/android-google-maps-api-v2-center-markers. This also worked for me thanks