# Center Marker on Google Maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I would like to center a Google Map marker on Android.
Indeed, a marker is center on the x-axis but is on the top of the specified point.

For this moment i'm doing this :

```
mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pos)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconeRotated)));
```

Where iconeRotated is a Bitmap object.

Comment: Welcome Tripper on stackoverflow. What you are trying yet?

Comment: Thank you pRaNaY. I edited my post and I hope that answer you question.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613940/android-google-maps-api-v2-center-markers

Comment: I don't think so. I just need to move the marker, not the global camera.