# Android: Algorithm to set zoom and location of Google map given a sets a points

Tags: android, algorithm, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an ArrayList, each of these LatLng is a marker on my map
The list can have anywhere from 0 to 1 to n points. They may or may not be distant within each others.

Can someone help me, given a height ("h"dp) and a width ("w"dp) of the map area, determine:

1. the "center" of this set
2. the appropriate zoom level (z) of this set, so that all markers are visible within the frame of size "h" by "w", but a (z+1) zoom level will not show all the points.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828217/android-map-v2-zoom-to-show-all-the-markers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the center of a set of LatLng points:

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
for (LatLng point: pointSet) {
   builder.include( point);
}
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
LatLng centerPoint = bounds.getCenter();
```

As for zooming, the simplest way would be to call map.animate:

```
mapObj.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, PADDING_VALUE));
```

Which is guaranteed to set the map to the greatest zoom level that contains the bounds input (plus padding).

And if you're still interested in knowing the required zoom level:

```
float zoomLevel = mapObj.getCameraPosition().zoom; // call after(!) animateTo
```