# Getting particular location of google map in center in android studio

Tags: android

I used this code to get particular location in center.

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(33.7167, 73.0667), 4))
```

It worked somehow but after putting `30` no of  markers simultaneously. I didn't get location in center.

this is my snippet of code

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvATG.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPsNx.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImmD8.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a930b.png

Comment: put your complete code with all the 30 markers on map

Comment: @SilvansSolanki Maybe you can re visit this thread again. I have edited the question so that the codes may be displayed. Thanks!

Comment: @RinkyKumari Please do preview first your question to avoid any lacking information next time :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can update camera to the center of bounds of markers. For that -

- Create `LatLngBounds.Builder` object and add all the markers in it.

  `LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();`
- While adding marker store it to variable like

  `Marker marker1 = mMap.addMarker(....);
   Marker marker2 = mMap.addMarker(....);`
- Then add all markers in it using

  `builder.include(marker1.getPosition());
  builder.include(marker2.getPosition());`
- Then build `LatLngBounds`

  `LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();`
- Then create `CameraUpdate` and animate camera to relative position

  `int padding = 0; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
  CameraUpdate camUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
  mMap.animateCamera(camUpdate);`

And done.

**Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828217/android-map-v2-zoom-to-show-all-the-markers) for more details.**

Hope it'll work.

Comment: hey, I posted it @ ELITE

Comment: Set `padding = 10;` instead of `0`.

Comment: If you're getting any error or exception, paste in the question.

Comment: google it out how to check `LogCat` in `AndroidStudio` and then paste the `Error LogCat` in the question..also check how to edit the question on `www.stackoverflow.com`.