# how to get which area has more markers from a LatLngBounds?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

i want to show all markers which is located in INDIA and AMERICA. This time LatLngBounds will show zoom level is 0 and map visible area between INDIA and AMERICA. Is there any solution for this? 
A solution for this,  if more markers are presented in INDIA, then just animate to INDIA else AMERICA. but how to get to know more markers are located in a country from a latlngbound?

Comment: you can refer from this link for latest api and map v2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828217/android-map-v2-zoom-to-show-all-the-markers

Comment: is `INDIA` and `AMERICA` just a static context.. ?

Comment: No it is dynamic one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just count when adding the markers to the map. With `AMERICA` and `INDIA` defined as `LatLngBounds`:

```
private void addMarkers(List<LatLng> positions) {
    int markersInAmerica = 0;
    int markersInIndia = 0;

    for (LatLng position : positions) {
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position));
        if (AMERICA.contains(position)) {
            markersInAmerica++;
        } else if (INDIA.contains(position)) {
            markersInIndia++;
        }
    }

    if (markersInAmerica > markersInIndia) {
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(AMERICA, 0));
    } else {
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(INDIA, 0));
    }
}
```

Ir you want to add all your markers first and then center the map you can define a `List<Marker>`, add your `Marker`s to the map and the list and then iterate over the list to center the map:

```
private List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<>();

private void addMarkers(List<LatLng> positions) {
    for (LatLng position : positions) {
        markers.add(googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position)));
    }
}

private void centerMap() {
    int markersInAmerica = 0;
    int markersInIndia = 0;

    for (Marker marker : markers) {
        if (AMERICA.contains(marker.getPosition())) {
            markersInAmerica++;
        } else if (INDIA.contains(marker.getPosition())) {
            markersInIndia++;
        }
    }

    if (markersInAmerica > markersInIndia) {
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(AMERICA, 0));
    } else {
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(INDIA, 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks.. but the country not always AMERICA and INDIA.. sometimes markers will be available other 10 countries also.. which country has more markers then move to that country..