# I want this..map zoom on my multiple markers, in one frame.right now my map zoom is showing centerlized position of country

Tags: java, android, google-maps, kotlin

```
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
int padding = (int) (width * 0.10); // offset from edges of the map 10% of screen

CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, width, height, padding);

mMap.animateCamera(cu)
```

below attached image you can check.

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXdMx.jpg)

Comment: I think you need to provide more of a minimal example to try and reproduce your problem

Comment: try this is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828217/android-map-v2-zoom-to-show-all-the-markers

Comment: Already applied this code but every time markers not set in center of the map. @Amitpandey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can calculate the bounds of all the markers you have:-

```
 val builder = LatLngBounds.Builder();
 for (builder in markers) {
 builder.include(marker.getPosition());
}
val bounds = builder.build();
```

Then obtain a movement object by using: CameraUpdateFactory:

```
val padding = 0; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
val cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
```

Finally the map:

```
googleMap.moveCamera(cu);
```

if you want to animate:

```
googleMap.animateCamera(cu);
```

you can reduce zoom to focus latlng is middle of the map

Answer (score 0):

remove you height and width and set padding 0 and try it because google map provide max zoom and show according to the screen.