# Custom InfoWindow on Left Side for Google Maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want a custom `InfoWindowAdapter` to be shown on the `Marker`.
I have already made a custom `InfoWindowAdapter` and implemented it but the problem is that by default it is shown above the `Marker` and I want it to be shown on the left side.

I went through some previous related question but didn't get a best answer.

Here is an image of what i want.

Thanks.[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Google Map API V2 : Open Custom Info Window on Right Side of Marker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357904/android-google-map-api-v2-open-custom-info-window-on-right-side-of-marker)

Comment: this is not possible right now in google map v2. check this http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4783 . what you can do is , go for an alternate option that look same but not actually have expected code. will you go for that???

Comment: @nads I made custom view, then converted view to bitmap and then placed it as marker icon. I know it is weired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from September update (v12 or 3.2.65) of the Google Maps Android API v2 [MarkerOptions.infoWindowAnchor](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions#infoWindowAnchor%28float,%20float%29) was added. There are quite a few new functions, so check [release notes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/releases#september_2013) too.

**Edit:**

Unfortunatelly this addition doesn't solve your problem yet. Added [new issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5842) for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `infoWindowAnchor()` when you add marker as shown;

```
marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(markerPosition).icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(MapActivity.this, R.drawable.user_marker)).title(title).infoWindowAnchor(3.1f,1.0f));
```