# Returns point(0, 0) for getting screen position of a LatLng object

Tags: android, position, screen, point

My code:

```
Point p1 = supportMapFragment
              .getMap()
              .getProjection()
              .toScreenLocation(new LatLng(20,20));
```

The problem is `p1` returns like: `Point(0, 0)`. There is a solution [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14430135/2175257), but that's useless for me. I keep that points in an `arrayList`. When I want to bring points from inside `arrayList`, it returns `[]`. I think the reason of that waiting the `addOnGlobalLayoutListener`. For this reason I should to find another and fast solution to get true values of points.

Answer (score 0):

You can try onWindowFocusChanged()

for example:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    Point p1 = supportMapFragment
          .getMap()
          .getProjection()
          .toScreenLocation(new LatLng(20,20));
}
```

At least I got it done using this method