# Issue with Google Maps toScreenLocation() method Android

Tags: android, google-maps, opengl-es-2.0, google-maps-api-2

As the title mentions, I'm having issues with the toScreenLocation() with Google Maps.

I'm trying to pick arbitrary points on Google Maps that I am broadcasting to my Google Maps fragment. Within the fragment, I want to get the Screen Point this LatLng coordinate corresponds with. However, most of the time I get an error like the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: left == right
        at android.opengl.Matrix.frustumM(Matrix.java:327)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.b.b.j(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.b.b.l(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.b.b.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.b.b.c(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.y.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.az.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ca.onTransact(SourceFile:74)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IProjectionDelegate$zza$zza.toScreenLocation(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.Projection.toScreenLocation(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.tracker.googlemaps.GoogleMapsTracker.convertCoordinates(GoogleMapsTracker.java:163)
        at com.example.tracker.googlemaps.GoogleMapsTracker.access$100(GoogleMapsTracker.java:38)
        at com.example.tracker.googlemaps.GoogleMapsTracker$2.onReceive(GoogleMapsTracker.java:153)
        at     android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:866)
```

The code that corresponds with the conversion is:

```
    private void convertCoordinates(float latitude, float longitude){
    location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    if(location.latitude != (float) 0.0 || location.longitude != (float) 0.0){
        //Point map = mapView.getMap().getProjection().toScreenLocation(location);

        Point map = projection.toScreenLocation(location);
        ScreenAdjustments.setLati(map.y);
        ScreenAdjustments.setLongi(map.x);
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "BAD COORDINATES!!!");
    }
}
```

I have verified that I am getting in float values and that they are what I hard coded them to be. But most of the time when it hits the Point map = projection.toScreenLocation(location); it will throw the error about the frustum.

I need help in figuring out how to get this to work.

Comment: What `latitude` and `longitude` values you tried?

Comment: The values don't matter. I can go anywhere between +/- 90 for latitude and +/- 180 for longitude and it will still throw the error most of the time.

Comment: Do you have the issue when you use `mapView.getMap().getProjection().toScreenLocation(location);`?

Comment: Yes. Both statements will give me the error.

Comment: Did you call `Matrix.frustumM` in your project? If so, make sure the `left` and `right` parameters are not the same, otherwise, it will throw an exception: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/opengl/java/android/opengl/Matrix.java#323

Comment: Matrix.frustumM is never called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first tried your code and got no error.

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14430135/4186942), I tired `toScreenLocation` and it works. Remember set `OnGlobalLayoutListener` to make sure the map view and waiting for layout process to settle.

Sample code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private static LatLng MountainView = new LatLng(37.42, -122.08);
    private static LatLng MountainView2 = new LatLng(37.421, -122.081);
    View mapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Initial Map
        try {

            if (mGoogleMap == null) {
                mGoogleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mapView = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map).getView();

        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

        //mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(MountainView, 15));

        Marker marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(MountainView)
                .title("Have a nice day!"));

        convertCoordinates((float) 37.42, (float) -122.08);

    }

    private void convertCoordinates(float latitude, float longitude) {
        final LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        if (location.latitude != (float) 0.0 || location.longitude != (float) 0.0) {
            if (mapView.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()) {
                mapView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        // remove the listener
                        // ! before Jelly Bean:
                        mapView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                        // ! for Jelly Bean and later:
                        //mapView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                        // set map viewport
                        // CENTER is LatLng object with the center of the map
                        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 15));
                        // ! you can query Projection object here
                        Point markerScreenPosition = mGoogleMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation(location);
                        // ! example output in my test code: (356, 483)
                        Log.d("x!!!!", markerScreenPosition.x + "");
                        Log.d("y!!!!", markerScreenPosition.y + "");
                    }
                });

            } else {
                //Log.e(TAG, "BAD COORDINATES!!!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works and output is `x = 639, y = 1049` on my Nexus 6.

Comment: Running your code I received an error at the Point variable again. This time with an IllegalArgumentException: left == right

Comment: Hi @Beren, I uploaded all working codes [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/toScreenLocation-googleMap-android), you can tried it yourself. You may try to change devices to run. Please try it.

Comment: Your code on its own does work. I'll try to work with something similar to this. Thank you.