# Fill Polygon with icons

Tags: android, google-maps

I am able to draw polygon inside Google map. Now when I finished drawing a polygon of the area on the map, I want to fill that polygon with the same icons. I can fill the polygon with color, but I want to fill it with icons with some padding at the border and some specified space between the icons. How can i do it?

Comment: if you are dealing with multiple polygons on map, by doing so your map will start lagging.

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit i want to fill out the area that the user draws on map. I can do this when it will add polyline latlong inside array but then it will fill border and not the inner part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "from the box" solution for Google Maps Android SDK [`Polygon`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon) fill with pattern (only solid fill), but you can use some workarounds.

**TLDR;**

Assume you need fill park polygon:

```
final List<LatLng> polygonPoints = new ArrayList<>();
polygonPoints.add(new LatLng(50.444477, 30.498976));
polygonPoints.add(new LatLng(50.445290, 30.500864));
polygonPoints.add(new LatLng(50.443958, 30.508921));
polygonPoints.add(new LatLng(50.443247, 30.508642));
polygonPoints.add(new LatLng(50.442830, 30.508878));
polygonPoints.add(new LatLng(50.440965, 30.508256));
polygonPoints.add(new LatLng(50.441949, 30.501443));

final Polygon polygon = mGoogleMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
        .addAll(polygonPoints)
        .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
        .fillColor(Color.argb(20, 0, 255, 0)));
```

[image: Source polygon]

with trees icons (`R.drawable.ic_forest`):

[image: Tile icon]

You can do it via:

1) "fill" by markers with customized (tree) icons. For do that you need to find polygon bounds rectangle and add markers in loop as square greed. For adding markers only inside polygon you can use [`PolyUtil.containsLocation()`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#containsLocation-double-double-java.util.List-boolean-) from [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/):

```
LatLngBounds bounds = getPolygonBounds(polygon.getPoints());

BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_forest);

double boundHeight = bounds.northeast.latitude - bounds.southwest.latitude;
double boundWidth = bounds.northeast.longitude - bounds.southwest.longitude;

double gridCntLat = 5;  // 5 icons vertically
double gridCntLon = 5;  // 5 icons horizontally

double dLat = (bounds.northeast.latitude - bounds.southwest.latitude) / gridCntLat;
double dLng = (bounds.northeast.longitude - bounds.southwest.longitude) / gridCntLon;

double lat = dLat + bounds.southwest.latitude;

while (lat < bounds.northeast.latitude) {
    double lon = dLng + bounds.southwest.longitude;
    while (lon < bounds.northeast.longitude) {

        LatLng iconPos = new LatLng(lat, lon);

        if (PolyUtil.containsLocation(iconPos, polygonPoints, true)) {
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(iconPos)
                    .draggable(false)
                    .flat(true)
                    .icon(icon);
            mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }
        lon += dLng;
    }
    lat += dLat;
}
```

where `getPolygonBounds()` is:

```
private LatLngBounds getPolygonBounds(List<LatLng> polygon) {
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < polygon.size() ; i++) {
        builder.include(polygon.get(i));
    }
    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    return  bounds;
}
```

and
    ...
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    ...

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    ...
}
```

As a result you got something like that:

[image: Filed by markers]

It's easiest solution, but some icons may be partially outside polygon border (you can slightly adjust them by [`MarkerOptions.anchor()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions#anchor(float,%20float)) method and also you can set [`MarkerOptions.flat(true)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html#flat(boolean)) if you want marker icons rotated with the polygon) and for large amount of markers map starts lagging.

2) use "dynamic" (programmatically created for each polygon) [`GroundOverlay`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay).  For do that you also need to determine polygon rectangle bounds and than create overlay bitmap with same proportions in pixels (also you need to limit it by the larger side to avoid Out of Memory (OOM) Error). NB you need to use [`Projection`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection) to calculate rectangle bounds because LatLng degrees at different latitudes and longitudes has different size in meters and than in pixels.

Than, you need draw polygon at created bitmap canvas. For do that you can use [`Path`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path) object with recalculated LatLng polygon points into local overlay bitmap coordinates in pixels. You should use simple proportion for that, not `Projection.toScreenLocation()`:

```
screenPoint.x = (int) (width * (latLng.longitude - bounds.southwest.longitude) / boundWidth);
screenPoint.y = height - (int) (height * (latLng.latitude - bounds.southwest.latitude) / boundHeight);  // y-axis of screen is inverted to Lat
```

For filling polygon on overlay bitmap with bitmaps of your icons you can use [`Shader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Shader) and set it to `Paint` object with [`Paint.setShader()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint#setShader(android.graphics.Shader)). Than, at last, you can add created bitmap as Ground Overlay on your GoogleMap object. Full source code of `fillPoly()` method, that fills `polygon` with `tileBitmap`:

```
private GroundOverlay fillPoly(Projection projection, Polygon polygon, Bitmap tileBitmap, float transparency) {
    LatLngBounds bounds = getPolygonBounds(polygon.getPoints());

    double boundHeight = bounds.northeast.latitude - bounds.southwest.latitude;
    double boundWidth = bounds.northeast.longitude - bounds.southwest.longitude;

    Point northEast = projection.toScreenLocation(bounds.northeast);
    Point southWest = projection.toScreenLocation(bounds.southwest);

    int screenBoundHeight = northEast.y - southWest.y;
    int screenBoundWidth = northEast.x - southWest.x;

    // determine overlay bitmap size
    double k = Math.abs((double) screenBoundHeight / (double) screenBoundWidth);
    int overlayWidth;
    int overlayHeight;
    if (Math.abs(boundWidth) > Math.abs(boundHeight)) {
        overlayWidth = OVERLAY_MAX_SIZE;
        overlayHeight = (int) (overlayWidth * k);
    } else {
        overlayHeight = OVERLAY_MAX_SIZE;
        overlayWidth = (int) (overlayHeight * k);
    }

    // create overlay bitmap
    Bitmap overlayBitmap = createOverlayBitmap(overlayWidth, overlayHeight, bounds, polygon.getPoints(), tileBitmap);

    // create ground overlay
    GroundOverlayOptions overlayOptions = new GroundOverlayOptions()
            .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(overlayBitmap))
            .transparency(transparency)
            .positionFromBounds(bounds);

    return mGoogleMap.addGroundOverlay(overlayOptions);
}
```

where `createOverlayBitmap()` is:

```
private Bitmap createOverlayBitmap(int width, int height, LatLngBounds bounds, List<LatLng> polygon, Bitmap tileBitmap) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    Path path = new Path();
    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(tileBitmap,
            Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setShader(shader);

    List<Point> screenPoints = new ArrayList<>(polygon.size());

    double boundHeight = bounds.northeast.latitude - bounds.southwest.latitude;
    double boundWidth = bounds.northeast.longitude - bounds.southwest.longitude;

    for (int i = 0; i < polygon.size(); i++) {
        LatLng latLng = polygon.get(i);
        Point screenPoint = new Point();
        screenPoint.x = (int) (width * (latLng.longitude - bounds.southwest.longitude) / boundWidth);
        screenPoint.y = height - (int) (height * (latLng.latitude - bounds.southwest.latitude) / boundHeight);
        screenPoints.add(screenPoint);
    }

    path.moveTo(screenPoints.get(0).x, screenPoints.get(0).y);
    for (int i = 1; i < polygon.size(); i++) {
        path.lineTo(screenPoints.get(i).x, screenPoints.get(i).y);
    }
    path.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    return bitmap;
}
```

And you can use it that way:

```
Bitmap tileBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_forest);   // create bitmap of fill icon
fillPoly(mGoogleMap.getProjection(), polygon, tileBitmap, 0.5f);
```

`mGoogleMap.getProjection()` needed for correct calculation of bitmap proportion. If you need use to use `mGoogleMap.getProjection()` before map rendered you should use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14430135/6950238) solution of [andr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1820695/andr).

As a result you got something like this:

[image: Polygon with Ground overlay]

If you need "some specified space between the icons" that spaces should be inside icon itself:

[image: Tile icon with spaces]

(h - horizontal space, v - vertical space).

Ground overlays always scaled and rotated with map and if you need zoom-independent icon you should use other approach. Also for large overlay bitmaps device may not have enough memory.

3) use [`Tile Overlays`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/tileoverlay). Actually it's like p.2 but overlay bitmap generated for each zoom level and splitted into small (e.g. 256x256 pixels) tiles for avoid high memory consumption. You can store generated tiles in device file system and implement [`TileProvider`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileProvider) like in ['this'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14833256/6950238) answer of [`Alex Vasilkov`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/687154/alex-vasilkov);

4) use [`custom`](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view) [`MapView`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView)-based view with overridden [`dispatchDraw()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#dispatchDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)) where you can take control of everything of drawing on view canvas. It's the best, but complex solution.

**NB! It's only demonstration - not the full solution (e.g. it didn't tested for negative LatLng etc.).**

Comment: Thanks Andrii it helped alot for reference.