# Android: how to arrange Latlog in android google so that it form rectangle polygon?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have 4 `LatLng`. For making a rectangle polygon, they should be in a list in either clockwise or anti-clockwise direction, so that when i add these `LatLng` in `addPolygon(new LatLng)` in google map it will create a rectangle shape.
But in my case, they might be in clockwise or anti-clockwise or in different form. One example is -> 1st `LatLng` followed by 3rd `LatLng` followed by 2nd `LatLng` followed by 4th `LatLng`. In this case, It will not create rectangle polygon on google map.
So I have to arrange it in clockwise or anti clockwise, so that the shape form must be rectangle, When i Put this `LatLng` list in `addPolygon()` in google map.

Suppose:

```
val rectOptions = PolygonOptions()
        .add(
            LatLng(37.35, -122.0),
            LatLng(37.45, -122.0),
            LatLng(37.45, -122.2),
            LatLng(37.35, -122.2)
        )
```

If I put `rectOptions` in `AddPolygon()` in `mMap.addPolygon(rectOptions)`
it will Create a rectangular shape on google map. In my case:

```
val rectOptions = PolygonOptions()
        .add(
            LatLng(37.45, -122.0),
            LatLng(37.45, -122.2),
            LatLng(37.35, -122.0),
            LatLng(37.35, -122.2)
        )
```

This will not create rectangular shape. So I have to arrange these `LatLng` so that they form rectangular shape.

Comment: show some codes

Comment: Actually it is a requirement. I have to write a program.

Answer (score 1):

In general your task is [Convex hull construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) and can be solved by one of [Convex hull algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms), e.g. like [Gift wrapping (aka Jarvis) algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm) in [this implementation](https://github.com/rraulinio/JarvisAlgorithm/blob/master/Jarvis.java).

Note that most of Convex hull algorithms implementations is for flat `(x,y)` point coordinates, not for `LatLng` location coordinates, so easiest way is to convert `LatLng` to flat `(x,y)` points with [`Projection.toScreenLocation()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection#toScreenLocation(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng)) method and than, after Convex hull algorithm apply, convert it back to `LatLng` with [`Projection.fromScreenLocation()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection#fromScreenLocation(android.graphics.Point)) method.

Also remember, that the [`Projection`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection) object will only return valid values after the map has passed the layout process (i.e. it has valid `width` and `height` set) and you can get it in [`OnCameraIdleListener`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener) or use approach, described by [andr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1820695/andr) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14430135/6950238).

So full demo source code can be like that:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private SupportMapFragment mMapSupportedFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mMapSupportedFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        mMapSupportedFragment.getMapAsync(MainActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;

        mGoogleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraIdle() {
                ArrayList<LatLng> sourcePoints = new ArrayList<>();
                sourcePoints.add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0));
                sourcePoints.add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.2));
                sourcePoints.add(new LatLng(37.40, -122.1));
                sourcePoints.add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.2));
                sourcePoints.add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.0));

                Projection projection = mGoogleMap.getProjection();
                ArrayList<Point> screenPoints = new ArrayList<>(sourcePoints.size());
                for (LatLng location : sourcePoints) {
                    Point p = projection.toScreenLocation(location);
                    screenPoints.add(p);
                }

                ArrayList<Point> convexHullPoints = convexHull(screenPoints);
                ArrayList<LatLng> convexHullLocationPoints = new ArrayList(convexHullPoints.size());
                for (Point screenPoint : convexHullPoints) {
                    LatLng location = projection.fromScreenLocation(screenPoint);
                    convexHullLocationPoints.add(location);
                }

                PolygonOptions polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions();
                for (LatLng latLng : convexHullLocationPoints) {
                    polygonOptions.add(latLng);
                }

                mGoogleMap.clear();
                Polygon polygon = mGoogleMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions.strokeColor(Color.argb(255, 49, 101, 187)).fillColor(Color.argb(100, 49, 101, 187)));
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean CCW(Point p, Point q, Point r) {
        return (q.y - p.y) * (r.x - q.x) - (q.x - p.x) * (r.y - q.y) > 0;
    }

    public ArrayList<Point> convexHull(ArrayList<Point> points)
    {
        int n = points.size();
        if (n <= 3) return points;

        ArrayList<Integer> next = new ArrayList<>();

        // find the leftmost point
        int leftMost = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            if (points.get(i).x < points.get(leftMost).x)
                leftMost = i;
        int p = leftMost, q;
        next.add(p);

        // iterate till p becomes leftMost
        do {
            q = (p + 1) % n;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                if (CCW(points.get(p), points.get(i), points.get(q)))
                    q = i;
            next.add(q);
            p = q;
        } while (p != leftMost);

        ArrayList<Point> convexHullPoints = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < next.size() - 1; i++) {
            int ix = next.get(i);
            convexHullPoints.add(points.get(ix));
        }

        return convexHullPoints;
    }
}
```

Also you can find more simple algorithm if you need to "sort" points only for rectangles (e.g. you need to test which 3 points form a right angle and add it from first to third and then add fourth point and so on).