# How to get a map pins screen position in .net maui (Android/iOS)

Tags: .net, dictionary, position, maui

I wish to open a popup next to a map pin (when pressed), but cannot figure out how to get the screen position of the Pin.

Adding the Pins to the map works fine:

```
  map.Pins.Add(nameOfPin);
```

..and creating an event handler is also straightforward:

```
  nameOfPin.MarkerClicked += OnPinClickedAsync;
```

The event handler below should open the popup next to the Pin, but I cannot get the Pins screen position. Map location is included in the sender object, but as far as I can tell, the screen position is not.

async void OnPinClickedAsync(object? sender, PinClickedEventArgs args)
{
var selectedPin = (Pin)sender;
. . .and then what?? How to get the Pins screen position (Android/iOS)
}

Can anyone help pls?

PS. I have tried to extraxt all information of the Pin object created by the event, but unable to find the pins screen position

Comment: If you just want to show a popup near the pin, you could try using [Handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/?view=net-maui-8.0).

Comment: Thanks for yoyr suggestion. Have tried that, but not sure I understand how to do it correctly. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [MKMapView.ConvertCoordinate Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/mapkit.mkmapview.convertcoordinate?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) for ios, which can convert a map coordinate to a point. For Android, you may refer to [How to get screen coordinates from marker in google maps v2 android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429877/how-to-get-screen-coordinates-from-marker-in-google-maps-v2-android)

To use them, you may [invoke platform code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code?view=net-maui-8.0).

Suppose below is the click event handler for a pin,

```
private void BoardwalkPin1_MarkerClicked(object? sender, PinClickedEventArgs e)
{
    var mypin = sender as Pin;
    float xPos;
    float yPos;

#if IOS
    var vc = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow?.RootViewController;
    while(vc.PresentedViewController != null)
    {
        vc = vc.PresentedViewController;
    }

    CLLocationCoordinate2D Coordinate = new CLLocationCoordinate2D(mypin.Location.Latitude, mypin.Location.Longitude);

    var myPoint = (mymap.Handler.PlatformView as MKMapView).ConvertCoordinate(Coordinate,vc.View);
    xPos = (float)myPoint.X;
    yPos = (float)myPoint.Y;
#elif ANDROID
    var map = (mymap.Handler as MapHandler)?.Map as Android.Gms.Maps.GoogleMap;
    Projection projection = map.Projection;
    LatLng markerLocation = new LatLng(mypin.Location.Latitude, mypin.Location.Longitude);
    Android.Graphics.Point screenPosition = projection.ToScreenLocation(markerLocation);
    xPos = (float)screenPosition.X;
    yPos = (float)screenPosition.Y;

#endif
    Console.WriteLine(xPos);
    Console.WriteLine(yPos);
}
```

`xPos` and `yPos` we get are the postition relative to the current view.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for this.
I get a  problem in the Android code though. The cast "as Android.Gms.Maps.GoogleMap" return null even though the "mymap.Handler.PlatformView" has a value. Any ideas?

Comment: You may try this ```var map = (mymap.Handler as MapHandler)?.Map as Android.Gms.Maps.GoogleMap;```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for this. It was a great help.